# Using your to refer to a company

Tags: grammar

For example:

> "Can you get sued for putting malware in your product?" the Microsoft
>   CEO asked the independent lawyer.

Can we use your to refer to the company? Why? Is it accepted or not?

Comment: Is it the lawyer's product? If the speaker is CEO of some unnamed company, they are responsible for what happens in that company, and speaks on its behalf. So it would be "Can **we** get sued for putting malware in **our** product?" Too often, people say sth like "You felt this, you did that," when they should cop to it and say "***I*** did."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a generic you.

That is, it is not referring to a specific person/company but the general case of whether those who put malware into a product can be sued.